# Java game - layout

Tags: java, layout

I'm making tetris in Java and I have a few questions about layout in reference to the picture below:

Should the gameboard and scoreboard be separated into two JPanels within ONE JFrame... Then just set the JFrame size equal to gameBoard + the Scoreboard?

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Tetris");  
f.setSize(gameBoard.getWidth()+scoreBoard.getWidth(), gameBoard.getHeight());
```

Or should it be 1 JPanel within 1 JFrame that contains everything...? (Here I set Frame equal to size of gameBoard + 200 on the right so I have space to show the buttons, score, next Piece, etc...) If so, how do I align those buttons and such?

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Tetris");  
f.setSize(gameBoard.getWidth()+200, gameBoard.getHeight());
```

Any thoughts on how I should lay out my game?

[image]

Comment: @SamIam is this supposed to be enigmatically helpful?

Comment: it may be easier for you to organize your code if you separate into 2 distincts Panel / JPanel

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and http://ux.stackexchange.com/ might be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use `setSize`. Use a layout, position all your components, and then call `f.pack`. This will automatically size the window correctly.
- You definitely should have more than one `JPanel`. Your two-panel layout looks good.

For example:

```
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
contentPane.add(mainGamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
contentPane.add(scorePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
f.setContentPane(contentPane);
f.pack();
```

See [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for more information.